# Casting route parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Working on a simple API, I noticed that my routing tests were failing because my `:id` params were strings and I was comparing them to integer values. Is there a way to automatically cast request parameters via routes.rb in some way? For example, given the following route (/profile/1), I'd like `params[:id]` to be an integer (1) rather than a string ("1"):

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1  do
    scope '/profile' do
      get ':id' => 'users#show', :id => /\d+/
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick example [from here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters):

```
match '/:id' => 'posts#show', :constraints => {:id => /^\d/}
```

Then you'd have to do

```
params[:id].to_i
```

in the controller action to cast it explicitly.  I'm not sure there is another way to do this directly in routes.rb without monkey-patching how Rails collects params.

Taken from the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters):

> The value of params[:ids] will now be ["1", "2", "3"]. Note that parameter values are always strings; Rails makes no attempt to guess or cast the type.

Comment: That makes sure the value is an integer like string, but I don't see how that actually recasts into an integer...

Comment: It appears there is no way to do that without monkey-patching Rails.  See updated answer.

Comment: I suppose I should be sanitizing that input anyway and never assume a cast even if it did do that.